# Clickable world map that returns the relivant 3166-1-alpha-2 country code

Tags: dictionary

I want to make a click-able world map which when a user clicks on a country it directs the user to a url containing the corresponding country code.

e.g you click on the UK and it directs you to .../country.php?c=GB

What would be the best way to go about it? html imagemaps? javascript? flash? Are there scripts already out there? Is there a way to use google maps?

Comment: This tutorial might help: [http://www.electricfairground.com/2009/08/08/image-map-rollover-effects-using-jquerys-maphilight-plugin/](http://www.electricfairground.com/2009/08/08/image-map-rollover-effects-using-jquerys-maphilight-plugin/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_world.html#

Answer (score 0):

You can construct such a clickable graphic using SVG.

Comment: I was hoping there might be something out there already... I imagine outlining and attaching the country codes of 246 countries would take forever :S . I guess if it comes to it then that's what I'll have to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to implement what you want with [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com) mapping library. To define an action on country click use a onRegionClick parameter. The country code according to the ISO format is available as a second parameter in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

I would, if I may, suggest to check out [Highmaps](http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo), from the people behind [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com) (myself included). It's free for non-commercial use, works great with mobile browsers (full touch support) and old IE down to IE6. It supports advanced dynamic features like drilldown and rich tooltips, and is very customizable.

We supply a [map collection](http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata) with over 350 maps, including several world map versions with ISO-3166-1-alpha-2 metadata embedded.

[image: Population history by country]
[image: Drainage basin of the Meuse river]